# How to fix Django's the view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead?

Tags: python, django

I'm getting the following error:

> The view KSUvity.authentication.views.registerAttendee didn't return
>   an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

I think it's because there is a logical error in my function. I have several if and else statements to check several conditions.

This is the function in views.py:

```
def registerAttendee(request,pk):
    act = Activity.objects.get(pk=pk)
    act.save()
    attendee, _ = Attendee.objects.get_or_create(student=request.user)

    volunteer = Volunteer.objects.filter(student=request.user)

    ActvsStudentAttending=Activity.objects.filter(attendee=attendee)
    ActvsStudentVolunteering=Activity.objects.filter(volunteer=volunteer)

    if act.volunteer.filter(student=request.user).exists():
        messages.error(request, 'You\'re already registered as a volunteer for this activity!', extra_tags='alert')
        return redirect('home/#work')

    elif act.attendee.filter(student=request.user).exists():
        messages.warning(request, 'You\'re already registered as an attendee for this activity!', extra_tags='alert')
        return redirect('home/#work')

    elif ActvsStudentAttending.exists():
        for x in ActvsStudentAttending:
            if x.startDate.date() == act.startDate.date():
                messages.error(request, 'You\'re already registered in the '+x.title+' activity that is held on the same day as '+act.title+'!', extra_tags='alert')
                return redirect('home/#work')

    elif ActvsStudentVolunteering.exists():
        for x in ActvsStudentVolunteering:
            if x.startDate.date() == act.startDate.date():
                messages.error(request, 'You\'re already registered in the '+x.title+' activity that is held on the same day as '+act.title+'!', extra_tags='alert')
                return redirect('home/#work')
    else:
        act.attendee.add(attendee)
        messages.success(request, 'You\'re successfully registered as an attendee!', extra_tags='alert')
        return redirect('home/#work')
```

Is the error being raised because of the inner if inside the for loop? If yes, how should I fix it? I don't have an else for these cases so I don't know what I'm missing here. I must check all conditions before getting to the final else that adds it into the model.

I'm new to Django and Python, so please excuse me.

This is what I have in models.py:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="owner")
    college = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    room = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    startDate = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    endDate = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    attendee = models.ManyToManyField(Attendee, related_name="attendees",null=True, blank=True)
    volunteer = models.ManyToManyField(Volunteer, related_name="volunteers",null=True, blank=True)

class Attendee(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="attendee")

class Volunteer(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="volunteer")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `else` and unindent its code block. That will ensure that this part of your code is always executed if your code went into one of the earlier `elif` blocks but never passed the inner `if` condition in the the loops:

```
if ...:
    # ...
elif ...:
    # ...
# remove the 'else', so that this will always run if your view function 
# did not return from any of the earlier '[el]if' blocks
act.attendee.add(attendee)
messages.success(request, 'You\'re successfully registered as an attendee!', extra_tags='alert')
return redirect('home/#work')
```